# How many dragon souls do I need to unlock all shouts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are 20 shouts in Skyrim, each with 3 levels of power. However, some of these shouts require dragon souls to unlock, and others are simply given to the player as gifts / quest rewards. (e.g., Clear Skies, Call Dragon, Call of Valor et al)

My question is:

What is the minimum number of dragons you must kill to be able to possess all 20 shouts at their full power?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[From what I see here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shout) it looks like 18 are learned without requiring dragon souls, though I'm extrapolating a bit since I haven't reached the end of the main quest yet, myself.

Fuzzy math:

```
Animal Allegiance     3 Souls    
Aura Whisper          3 Souls    
Become Ethereal       3 Souls
Call Dragon           0 Souls* 
*I'm making the assumption that this works a bit like Unrelenting Force
Call of Valor         0 Souls
Clear Skies           0 Souls
Disarm                3 Souls
Dismay                3 Souls
Dragonrend            0 Souls
Elemental Fury        3 Souls
Fire Breath           2 Souls
Frost Breath          3 Souls
Ice Form              3 Souls
Kyne's Peace          3 Souls
Marked for Death      3 Souls
Slow Time             3 Souls
Storm Call            3 Souls
Throw Voice           3 Souls
Unrelenting Force     1 Soul
Whirlwind Sprint      2 Souls
```

So...3+3+3+0+0+0+3+3+0+3+2+3+3+3+3+3+3+3+1+2 = **44**

Comment: I read it as 41 as well, also not having done most of the main quest.

Comment: Which ones are you referring to? Trying to go by the page, I count 46, so it sounds like I'm forgetting something...

Comment: Yeah something doesn't seem right here; I'm going to recalculate and add the calculation to the answer.

Comment: Okay, now I've got 42 instead...how are you getting 46? Do the ones I have marked as zero require one soul to begin with?

Comment: why do you have throw voice at 0 souls, you need 3 souls to fully unlock it

Comment: Ah. I forgot the first unrelenting force technically requires one soul.

Comment: Ah, that would be the issue then; 45 it is.

Comment: Fire Breath should be 2 because first word is unlocked during the quest The Throat of The World. Unrelenting Force should be 0 all are unlocked in the questline. Summary 43 souls needed.

Comment: @Manny You're right about Fire Breath, but Unrelenting Force (even though it's unlocked in the questline) still requires the dragon soul from western watch tower.

Comment: Just commenting on the math... the total of words for 20 shouts would be 60. Assuming you have listed the "quest learned" shouts, or parts of shouts, correctly, then you would only be getting 16 words of power from quests. That is why the math wasn't working out. You were correct about how many words of power you have to learn using dragon souls, which is 44.