# What can I use my extra dragon souls for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Dragons seem to breed like rabbits and they [keep at it forever](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/can-i-continue-to-harvest-dragon-souls-after-the-main-quest-is-over).

After collecting the [~44](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39979/2923) dragon souls needed to unlock all the shouts what can I do with extra souls I collect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On completing the Dragonborn DLC quest line, you have the ability to use dragon souls for clearing  perk trees. This gives you back the perks spent in the tree while keeping your skill level in that tree the same. If you've got the souls, you can do this as often and with as many skills as you like.

Answer (score 13):

There is currently a mod that allows you to trade dragon souls for perk points [here](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2063) if you're playing on the PC. Other than that, I can't think of anything.

Comment: There are similar mods available for [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4158890) and [Xbox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3038478)

Answer (score 10):

There is currently nothing you can do with extra souls.  It would be nice of a mod or DLC came out that allowed you to turbocharge a shout at the expense of a soul or something.

Comment: Or if you could use a dragon soul to SUPER enchant an item

Comment: Guessing the upvotes to this comment are due to its humorous nature?